# Slack bolt-app: No conversation ID for incoming event

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-commands, bolt

Hello and thanks for reading my request for help.

I have a slack bot that's based on `"@slack/bolt": "^3.6.0"`. When a command `/open-modal` is sent from the client, a modal opens up and lists a few options for next steps. When a user selects one of the options (buttons), a new view is pushed that presents the user with an input field and a submission button. All of this works as designed.

However, I noticed that in my debugging console, a message appears when a new view is pushed to the modal

```
[DEBUG]  bolt-app No conversation ID for incoming event
```

and an unexpected result takes place when the user clicks on the 'submit' button after filling in their data into the input field. the view receives the submission and will debug the input field to the console after validating that there are no errors but the modal doesn't close for the client (presents a `We had some trouble connecting. Try again?` error) and the next action to post the data to the channel doesn't execute.

I felt that the "No conversation ID for incoming event" was related to an incorrect callback plugin being referenced, but the fact that my view can send the user's input to the console kills that theory.

After three days, I'm here posting for guidance on possible next steps. Please let me know if any of the code would be beneficial

Answer (score 2):

three days of troubleshooting (wish I was paid by the hour), and I discover the answer three seconds after posting to Stack Overflow. This website is awesome.

My problem was within my json payload, I was referencing an object that did not exist.

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly you fixed it?